# Generate JSON schema from dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jsonschema

I want to extract a JSON schema ([as defined here](http://json-schema.org/examples.html)) from an object of type *dynamic*.

[This is the best example I could find](http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/using-json-net-to-generate-jsonschema/).

But JSON.NET's Schema Generator needs to look at an actual class/type to be able to generate a schema.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could extract a schema from a dynamic object?

Comment: You have tagged this question with my library (json-schema-validator) which is Java yet it appears you program in .NET... Therefore I am not sure what you are asking here. In Java you have jsonschema2pojo which can generate POJO source code from "arbitrary" JSON, and JJSchema which can generate schemas from "arbitrary" Java sounrce, but I feel none of these answer your question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback FGE. I didn't think that the tag related specifically to your library. My intention was to tag schema validation in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use `JSON.NET` to extract a `JSON` schema from dynamic object. You just need an actual object of type dynamic to be able to do that. Try the following sample:

```
dynamic person = new
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe"
            };

JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator {};

JsonSchema schema = schemaGenerator.Generate(person.GetType());
```

The generated `JSON` schema should look like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "Id": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "FirstName": {
            "required": true,
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        "LastName": {
            "required": true,
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It also adds looot of other properties like Hidden,Transient,Description etc. which I would like not to have. How to hide them from schema?

Comment: @Vlado: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HY4pxW I don't see the properties you talk about.

Answer (score -7):

If you are using .NET 4.0+ then there is a method System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode that converts JSON into a dynamic object:

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
// convert json to a dynamic object:
var myObject = Json.Decode(json);

// or to go the other way and get json from a dynamic object:
string myJson = Json.Encode(myObject);
```

To reference this assembly you can find it in the Extensions group under Assemblies in Visual Studio 2012.

This should be able solve your problem.  If you can include a sample of the JSON it would be clearer.

Comment: Thanks, but I can easily get a dynamic object out of some provided JSON. What I *need* to do is generate a json-schema for that newly created dynamic object. It doesn't really matter what the JSON is, as long as it's valid.

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear from your question, a little code sample would have helped.  That's simple, just go the opposite way and call `Json.Encode()` - answer has been updated

Comment: Not quite :) - You'll see in my question that I'm not trying to convert my dynamic object back to JSON, but instead generate a **JSON Schema** from the dynamic object, which is different than JSON. See here: http://json-schema.org/

Comment: @JK. it was pretty clear in the question since that's precisely what a  JSON schema *is* -- it's not about encoding/decoding JSON into C# types.